No more simultaneous dates?
I have noticed that in the timeline, hovering over timestamps events that occurred at the same time as others no longer shows S for simultaneous dates.
For example, normally, when an edit review task is completed as approved, and the corresponding suggested event, happen at the same time and show as simultaneous when hovering over the timestamp.
Old screenshot:

However, starting recently, the S for simultaneous dates never show. I returned to the exact same post later to demonstrate that events that previously showed as simultaneous (when hovering over the S) no longer do:

This is just an example; to reproduce, find any recently approved edit, or Q&A pair created at once using the answer your own question Q&A style and hover the timestamps in the timeline, and observe that no dates dates are marked as simultaneous. This is a in the timeline of a Q&A pair I created and the asked and answer added events used to show as simultaneous:

Please fix this, I miss being able to see which events happened coincidentally at similar times, or at the exact same time at a system level.
In case this matters, I am using Firefox, but could also reproduce this on Safari.

Fix is on its way. Updates in this answer.

@HamVocke I can confirm that this has been fixed. Thank you.
